# JQuery Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In Chrome debugger I get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when it parses this bit of code:

```
var pay = '{{payt}}';

if (pay.contains('visa')){
 $('#visa').prop('checked', true);
}
```

However this causes no problems in Firefox and executes the code. What woould cause this error?

EDIT: `indexOf()` works -

```
if (pay.indexOf("visa")!=-1){
 $('#visa').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains), the .contains function is not supported in chrome yet.

Comment: Newer versions of Chrome support the method.

Comment: Oh, odd. Well I see the article was last updated in February, so maybe it's outdated.

Comment: I installed my version this week to, so it should support contains()

Comment: @user94628 So, you don't want to support the older browsers? Check the polyfill in the linked MDN's entry.

Comment: @undefined, I do need to support older browsers, especially if contains()  doesn't work in my uptodate version of Chrome

Comment: @user94628: just be old school and use `.indexOf`.

Comment: @FelixKling, Old School seems to be the option that works here for both FF and Chrome browsers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the "undefined" user said, a polyfill is your best bet for ECMAScript functions that do not yet exist in the standard browsers.

```
if ( !String.prototype.contains ) {
  String.prototype.contains = function() {
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply( this, arguments ) !== -1;
  };
}
```

Source:
[MDN for String.prototype.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)